# Format part of text in TextField

Tags: ios, swift, formatting, textfield

I have implemented a text field in my iOS App and now I want a different formation for a passage of the text.

I find in the forum the suggestion to use the following code:

```
var temp:String = "Hello World"
let attrsBold = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)]
let txTeam1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: temp, attributes: attrsBold)
```

What now happened is, that the text is not formatted but is written with the following information in the text field:

> HelloWorld{NSFont =” font-familiy:
>   \”.SFUIText-Semibold\”;font-weight: bold; font-style: normal;
>   font-size: 15.00pt”;}

The text is set to the text field as follows:

```
textBericht.text = gameResult[0].bericht
```

The variable gameResult is written by a function:

```
gameResult = game.calculateGame(basic: gameBasic)
```

What I doing wrong? It seems the app is not interpreting the text after "Hello World".

Comment: Can you write the code where you set the attributedString to the textfield?

Comment: You should use the attributedText property of textfield to set it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the text with

```
textBericht.attributedText = temp
```